# How to include o values results in COUNT? SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count shutouts for goalies. I have two tables ("players" and "gamestats"). I have a problem getting the values when goalie has no  "0" / zero values in "goalsagainst" column when the goalie is "dressed" (has games).
So, I need to count all the zero values from column "goalsagainst" when "dressed" column has a value 1 as a "shutout" column. And if values from column "goalsagains" are more than 0 "shutout" colmn values should be 0;

I have tried the other solutions from similar topics, but I always have the same outcome where only the zero values are counted and other values are not shown.

```sql
My structure:
players
|p_id|pos|
--------
| 1 | G |
--------
| 2 | D |
--------
| 3 | O |
--------
| 4 | G |

stats
|g_id|p_id|goalsagainst|dressed|
--------------------------------
|  1 |  1 |    2       |  1    |
--------------------------------
|  1 |  4 |    0       |  0    |
--------------------------------
|  1 |  3 |    NULL    |  1    |
--------------------------------
|  1 |  2 |    NULL    |  1    |
--------------------------------
|  2 |  1 |    0       |  0    |
--------------------------------
|  2 |  4 |    0       |  1    |
--------------------------------
|  2 |  3 |    NULL    |  1    |
--------------------------------
|  2 |  2 |    NULL    |  1    |
```

```sql
   SELECT 
      stats.id,
      COUNT(stats.goalsagainst) AS shutouts 
   FROM `stats` 
      RIGHT JOIN players 
      ON stats.id = players.id
   WHERE goalsagainst = 0 
      AND players.pos = 'G' 
      AND stats.dressed = 1 
      GROUP BY stats.id;
```

```sql
my result is:

p_id|shutouts
-------------
 4  |    1    

when it should be:

p_id|shutouts
-------------
 1  |    0    
-------------
 4  |    1
```

Comment: do you mean `ON stats.p_id = players.p_id` in the join?

Comment: yes. I forgot to change that to my example.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your conditions on the `stats` table in your `WHERE` clause effectively turn the `RIGHT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. To work around this, move the conditions to the `ON` clause. Secondly, you need to use `players.p_id` in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` as `stats.p_id` may be `NULL`:

```
SELECT players.p_id,
       COUNT(stats.goalsagainst) AS shutouts 
FROM `stats` 
RIGHT JOIN players ON stats.p_id = players.p_id AND stats.dressed = 1 AND stats.goalsagainst = 0 
WHERE players.pos = 'G' 
GROUP BY players.p_id;
```

Output:

```
p_id    shutouts
1       0
4       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5eSchokesep4U3EjSSGNXK/0)